# Python library for looking patterns in an image

Tags: python, image

Im looking for a python library that could search an image and find the coordinates of smaller image file i give like the one in https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions. For example if i had https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWfBm.png
and i wanted to find all the spots with wild grass what would be the library that could help me do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the OpenCV library and link to the Python bindings in the system path. If you don't know how to do this, try Youtube for instructions that pertain to your operating system. From there, save an image containing one block of grass.

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np 

world = cv2.imread("world.png") # entire world image  
grass = cv2.imread("grass.png") # grass image

result = cv2.matchTemplate(world, grass, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)  
print np.unravel_index(result.argmax(), result.shape)
```